# Combine $FirebaseObject and multi location updates

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Is there a way to do a multi-location update when using a $FirebaseObject?

When i try it like this i get an error "Firebase.update failed: First argument  contains an invalid key ($id) in property"

```
            var customerData = {};
            customerData["Customers/" + user.uid] = firebaseObject;
            customerData["ProjectOverview/" + user.uid] = "value";
            ref.update(customerData);
```

I could use the solution in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508291/copy-a-firebaseobject-and-save-it-to-a-different-location) but that doesn't seem like the best way to do this.

Is there a better way to do multi-location updates when using a $FirebaseObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$firebaseUtils.toJSON()`, which [AngularFire uses in its `$save()` method](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/427d7f90c4c94c23eefebe6aec79085b58dfd06e/src/FirebaseObject.js#L76):

```
var customerData = {};
customerData["Customers/" + user.uid] = $firebaseUtils.toJSON(firebaseObject);
customerData["ProjectOverview/" + user.uid] = "value";
ref.update(customerData);
```