# Push AngularFire array directly to Firebase on other location

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have AngularFire array and I want to push the data it holds into a new location in my Firebase Database at some point.  I try to do it using the `push` method of Firebase SDK with no success. It gives me an error:

```
firebase.push failed first argument contains invalid key ($id) ....
```

It seems that Firebase doesn't like the dollar signs that AngularFire adds. There are also some `$$` in the names of the methods in the sync array.

My question is, what is the proper way to get rid of this `$` signs and methods before I push my data?

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508291/copy-a-firebaseobject-and-save-it-to-a-different-location) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36845931/combine-firebaseobject-and-multi-location-updates)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AngularFire, try using the `.$add` instead.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('myReference');

var array = $firebaseArray(ref);
array.$add(data)
```

Here are the docs on it: https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#addnewdata

Comment: But won't l it download the whole data from the location this way ?

Comment: Yeah it will download all of the contents.

Comment: The node could have hundred of megabytes so I wanted to use the push method instead.

Comment: Fair enough, you'll have to strip out the $'s on your own then

Comment: I am experimenting now.In a loop I copy only meaning data into new array, delete $ properties and it looks like it will work.Will answer later.

Comment: Don't forget to loop through children's properties too!